# using fopen in hadoop streaming

Tags: hadoop, native, hadoop-streaming

How can I open file inside native application when I execute it using hadoop streaming?

For example I have code which looks like below:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
   FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "a+");
   ...
   fscanf(fp, "%d", val);
   ...
   fclose(fp);
}
```

If it is nt possible can you suggest any other way to do it or recommendations related to it.

If possible are there any docs for this topic. How to not program for hadoop-streaming.

Sorry for my English.

Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting when trying your code?  If you are trying to read/write a file, that should work, but there are a few things to keep in mind when doing this in Hadoop such as how your working directory will change and even the machine this code runs on will change.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 139
 at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:362)
 at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:576)
 at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:136)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:57)
 at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:391)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:325)

Comment: at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:266)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
 at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1278)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:260)
2012-10-18 04:21:56,498 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Runnning cleanup for the task

Comment: in general, it shows map 0%, reduce 0%, waits for a while and kills job. in log its written that it created 7 map jobs and all failed, or killed

Comment: Those exceptions do not show the problem with your C code.  Look at the job's logs in the web UI to see if something (like Segmentation Fault) is being printed to track down the error.  If not, you will need to debug/trace through your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I open file inside native application when I execute it using Hadoop streaming?

HDFS provides a REST API through [WebHDFS](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.3/webhdfs.html) and [HttpFS](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-hdfs-httpfs/index.html) for various operations. The REST API can be pragmatically accessed from all the languages. Also note that these languages also have libraries to program against REST API easily.

Comment: Thank you for answer, actually I meant opening file from native filesystem, but seems I learn new thing :) and figured out about how to open files from native fs.